# Image beside a div - HTML

Tags: html, css, image

Im working on a page, where I have a div on the left with 40% width (a contact card info) and on the right I want to put a picture next to it. The problem is, the picture is bigger than the width of the page. The way I would want it to display is like this: contact div on the left and another div with that picture next to it that has the same height as the contacts div and is positioned in the center of the div. So for example if the pic is 1000x800 it would only be displayed 500x250 but going from center of the image, not the upper left corner.

It is something very similar to this, except I don't want the email contact form on the right:
http://lubie.co/contact/

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could provide your code. on jsfiddle.net fon instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use that:
**HTML:**

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
   <div id="left"></div>
   <div id="right"></div>
   <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#left{
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    float: left;
    width:40%;
}

#right{
    background-color:#000;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
    width:60%;
}
```

And to use an image instead of a color on background, just use `background-image`

**JsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/just1ed3/2/

Comment: That's almost what I'm looking for, except the shown image needs to be at the centre of the picture

Comment: Could you link me to the image or one image like it?

Comment: It's ok, nevermind. I made an image with the exact size. Thanks!